# Facebook object debugger: Could not retrieve data from URL. (200)

Tags: debugging, facebook-like, share, meta-tags

When i use the object debugger, the scraper is not able to see my OG content on my page. The debugger says "Can't download: Could not retrieve data from URL.", even though it's a 200 OK and shows the correct fetched and canonical URL. I have a subdomain on it, and it work fine.So not sure what happen to my main domain.
When click on Scraped URL See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL , it just show blank page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your site seems to have some HTML errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fspandooly.de

You should fix them before attempting to validate your site.

Funny thing, I create a copy of your page, and it seems to validate with no changes in the HTML. Your webserver might be doing something weird (according to the headers, the `charset` is missing or none):

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webniraj.com%2Fspandooly.html

Comment: Unbelievable. I've been searching for 2 days and 2 nights after the error and everything what was missing was the character set!??(But I also have to clean up another 300 errors)
THANK YOU !!!

Comment: I have charset but still facing this issue. Any leads?

Comment: You should post a new question with the details for your site and the error you are getting so we can see the specific issue you are experiencing. This particular question / answer is over 10 years old.