# Magento Store URLS don't use the info to show in FB

Tags: facebook, magento, facebook-like, magento-1.7

I've develop an online store, and created a FB app, and integrated with a social share module.
As you can see in this page ( http://www.citromen.com/en/c/c3-ii/travagem/discos-de-trav-o-frente-ebc-ultimate-sloted-rotor.html ) I've the xml namespaces in html tag, the og:xpto tags in head...
I've I try to share, don't show the title, description or image.

What I'm missing? :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FB Open Graph page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/ they some the xml namespaces to opengraph and facebook in html tag.
I've that in my page and do not work...

In the test suggested by @R.S. I remove these two namespaces... Started to work...

Thanks for the guide...

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that the result is cache by facebook.

Did you try clearing facebook cache using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Also see [Facebook object debugger: Could not retrieve data from URL. (200)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786209/facebook-object-debugger-could-not-retrieve-data-from-url-200)

Comment: Yes, I try to use the tool, the code is 200, but the tool don't fetch the data... 
Because I fail all my ideas, I need the community to help in this matter... :(
Edit: Thanks for the second link!

Comment: Did you take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786209/facebook-object-debugger-could-not-retrieve-data-from-url-200