# Image not appearing when publishing to stream

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm writing a PHP app that posts to users' feeds.  The posts are showing up in the feeds, but the images I'm specifying aren't.

App is currently in sandbox mode, so not sure if that makes a difference.

Here is the data array I'm passing:

```
$data = array(
  'message'     => 'I just donated to ORGANIZATION to help end the needless killing of healthy animals.',
  'name'        => 'Each day over 10,000 healthy pets are killed. Together we can help change this.',
  'caption'     => 'petbucks.net',
  'link'        => 'http://petbucks.net',
  'description' => 'Sponsorship of real homeless pets gives them the time they need to find a forever home.',
  'picture'     => 'http://dev.petbucks.net/img/default-donation.jpg',
  'actions'     => array(
    array(
      'name' => 'Visit us',
      'link' => 'http://petbucks.net'
    )
  )
);

Facebook::api('/'.$uid.'/feed', 'post', $data);
```

Like I said, the post **is** appearing in the user's feed, but the picture isn't.  If I inspect the source of where the URL should be, here is the image tag that appears:

```
<img class="shareMediaPhoto fbStoryAttachmentImage img" src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y4/r/-PAXP-deijE.gif" alt="" style="background-image: url(https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/app_full_proxy.php?app=332280520247212&amp;v=1&amp;size=z&amp;cksum=534f379420f4d890f47eebaa5bf15f4a&amp;src=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.petbucks.net%2Fimg%2Fdefault-donation.jpg);">
```

Based on that, I'd say that it's receiving the picture URL just fine (you can see the real URL in the source of that background image), so it must be something else.  Is it because of sandbox mode?

Any idea what's going on would be appreciated!

### Update

There was some weird DNS issues going on, so those have been fixed.  However, I am now seeing full-size images in my main news feed, but not smaller ones in my own newsfeed.

This is going to be hard to demonstrate without giving out access to my FB account, but as an example, take a look at this post which I've made public:

https://www.facebook.com/colin.viebrock/posts/10153814802000226?stream_ref=10

That image shows correctly for me when I'm logged into FB, but not for you I'm guessing.  The URL it is trying to display is:

https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/app_full_proxy.php?app=332280520247212&v=1&size=z&cksum=15a4249f3c830d8818ed66e793ba3156&src=https%3A%2F%2Fpetbucks.org%2Fimg%2Fdefault-donation.jpg

When it does show up, it's referencing this image:

https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQD1l81SkouNC200&w=154&h=154&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpetbucks.org%2Fimg%2Fdefault-donation.jpg&cfs=1&upscale

Comment: May be you should validate your html page, as answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786209/facebook-object-debugger-could-not-retrieve-data-from-url-200. Because you can't even to scrape the page URL at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpetbucks.net

Comment: Well, that's bizarre.  I can get to the site just fine, but the scrapper is seeing a "Welcome to nginx" page. I'll look into that first, for sure.